# Trouble with S_ISXXX(m) macros from sys/stat.h

Tags: c, unix, filesystems, posix

I'm having trouble with `S_ISXXX(m)` macros from `sys/stat.h`

Specifically almost everything is reported as directory. Only regular files are correctly reported as regular files, links, devices, fifos, all seem to be reported as directories.

Am I missing something, or is this generally bugged?

Here's the code, should be pretty straightforward (sorry for the Czech text, but you should get the idea even without understanding that :)

```
int listdir(const char *path)
{
        struct dirent *polozka;
        DIR *dir;

        dir = opendir(path);
        if (dir == NULL) 
        {
                perror("nepovedlo se otevrit adresar");
                return -1;
        }

        while((polozka = readdir(dir)))
        {
                struct stat info;
                lstat(polozka->d_name,&info);
                puts(polozka->d_name);
                if (S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tObycejny soubor");
                if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tAdresar");
                if (S_ISCHR(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tZnakove zarizeni");
                if (S_ISBLK(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tBlokove zarizeni");
                if (S_ISFIFO(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tPojemenovana roura");
                if (S_ISLNK(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tSymbolicky link");
                if (S_ISSOCK(info.st_mode))
                        puts("\tSocket");
        }

        closedir(dir);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think they are buggy - show your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking whether `lstat` actually worked, and I'm guessing it is failing.

`polozka->d_name` contains only the filename without the path. If `path` in your example is something else than the current directory, most of the `lstat` calls will fail, leaving `info` in an undefined state.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be that trivial :) Thx